# Is it bad practice to reference a static method from a child class?

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, inheritance

I got a warning from the IDE saying,

> The static method setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(boolean) from the type JFrame should be accessed in a static way

I want to know which is more correct:
to reference from the declaring class (`JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);`),

or the inheriting class (`MyJFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call the method on the class where it was declared.

Calling it on sub-classing will also work, but since static methods cannot really be inherited/overridden that seems a bit confusing.

For the same reason, I would also avoid having a static method of the same name/signature than one of your parent classes.

These recommendations are definitely *not* "more object-oriented", but that is my point here: Since normal OO-thinking does not translate well to static methods, steer clear entirely.

Answer (score 1):

JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated would be a preferred way in my view, because if you use DynamicWindow.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated it becomes less obvious were the method comes from. I would think that you've created the same method in the subclass to hide the original one in superclass.

So, it's just less obvious for those who will read your code.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);` would be the appropriate way to invoke said static method.

To elaborate on the third sentence in Thilo's answer, **you can't override static methods**. It just can't be done.

If you create a new static method with the same signature as existing static method, you're merely shadowing the original one and anyone using your code will get confused.

Remember that which method is invoked depends on, in the case of static methods, the **reference type**. In the case of instance methods it depends on the **instance type**.

**Static methods are a code smell.** Use other's static methods only where you must, don't create your own.

Comment: "Don't create your own.". That's a bit extreme. You can put utility code that does not really need to belong to any object into classes full of static methods (that you can then import statically). Things like Commons Lang StringUtils. Just don't mix it with OOP too much. Maybe we can agree that static methods should be confined to final classes with only static methods (`JFrame` would be in violation of this rule).

Comment: I think static methods impedes testability and introduces tight coupling, which leads to all kinds of bad things. Some would consider utility classes an abomination. 

Reusing "standard" utility classes, such as the one as you mentioned, Commons Lang StringUtils is where I would draw the line. Not implementing your own static methods/utility classes should always be the goal. 

I guess if you must implement static methods in a utility class, restricting "subclassing" such as you suggest would be a good way to prevent further bad things from happening. 

In my humble opinion of course.